# How do I get a hold of kCBAdvDataManufacturerData in CoreBluetooth Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-bluetooth

I have a Broadcom BLE peripheral broadcasting data which includes a serial number being advertised in the form of a manufacturer's data. When I try to pick it up in iOS (Swift) I have trouble figuring out how to turn it into a variable or constant.

I am able to execute:

```
println("\(advertisementData)")
```

'advertisementData' is built into the centralManager function. And in the console I get:

[kCBAdvDataIsConnectable: 0, kCBAdvDataLocalName: mangos, kCBAdvDataManufacturerData: <08e19515 ec7e49fd af85c719 37332ccd cafebabe>]

which is swell, but I need to compare the data in kCBAdvDataManufacturerData with a string and have it execute a function if they are the same.

How exactly would I create a variable that accesses the serial number/kCBAdvDataManufacturerData? I've tried a number of different routes.

Code for the function:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    let localData = advertisementData as NSDictionary


println(localData.objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey))


var localName: NSString!
if (localData.objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) == nil)
{
    localName = ""
}
else{
    localName = localData.objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as! NSString

    if (localName == "test"){

        println("Test Found!")
        println("\(advertisementData)")
    }
}

self.tLog(NSString(format: "Discovered %@, RSSI: %@\n", localName, RSSI))
self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral

if (self.verboseMode())
{
    self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ack. Figured it out:

```
println(advertisementData["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"] as! NSData)
```

Comment: did you try converting it to Integer Array